# Nginx Installed w/Passenger but No Command Line

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phusion-passenger

I installed Passenger and Nginx on Ubuntu 12.10 using the following command: passenger-install-nginx-module (following instructions at www.modrails.com/documentation/Users guide Nginx.html). When I ran into problems installing my SSL certificate, I found that command line tools like "Nginx -V" produced the following output: "The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages..."

Update: I've succeeded in configuring SSL correctly using the instructions at the following link: https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/ssl

I still need to know how to run Nginx commands from the command line. No problems starting and stopping it using the scripts I installed to /etc/init.d/nginx. The nginx install directory is /opt/nginx.

Comment: Why? I'd just start-stop it with the scripts in init.d, or upstart.. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to know the version of Nginx, I'm running. Every source I've checked tells me to run nginx -V, which doesn't work with my setup. Thank you.

Comment: You want to symlink nginx to usr/sbin: `cd /usr/sbin && ln -s /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`